# PyMongo: Unable to update entries older than 7 days. Need to handle ISODate

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I'm trying to create a script that will update entries in Mongo that have a pending status, that where created more than 7 days ago.  However, I'm having issues that seem to stem from how the creation date is stored.

I run the following command in mongodb:

```
db.jobs.find( {"$and":[{"status": "PENDING"},{"createdOn":{"$lt":ISODate('2020-11-30T00:00:00.00000')}}]})
```

Where the ISODate is 7 days ago.  I get the entries created before then (note: I'm not sure why $lt is works for this, but when I do $gt, I do not get any results).  The createdOn field in the entries returned looks like this:

```
"createdOn" : ISODate("2020-11-20T18:50:40.062Z")
```

When I run a similar batch of code in python:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pymongo
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

newDate = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=7)

pendingJobs = list(db.jobs.find( {"$and":[{"state": "PENDING"},{"createdOn":{"$lt":newDate}}]}))
print(pendingJobs)
```

The date is returned in the following format:

```
'createdOn': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 20, 18, 50, 40, 62000)
```

This seems to be preventing me from using pymongo to update the status field with:

```
db.jobs.update( {"$and":[{"state": "PENDING"},{"createdOn":{"$lt":newDate}}]}, { "$set": {"status":"FAILED"} })
```

Since pymongo runs with datetime, and Mongo runs with ISODate.  How can I account for this?  I've already tried the following with no effect:

- formatting newDate as an ISODate

```
isoDate = newDate.isoformat()

db.jobs.update( {"$and":[{"state": "PENDING"},{"createdOn":{"$lt":isoDate}}]}, { "$set": {"status":"FAILED"} })
```

- Trying to incorporate "ISODate" into the string itself:

```
db.jobs.update( {"$and":[{"state": "PENDING"},{"createdOn":{"$lt":"ISODate('"+isoDate+"')"}}]}, { "$set": {"status":"FAILED"} })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pymongo drivers will map a python `datetime.datetime` to a BSON `date` which you see represented in the shell as an `ISODate`. So you first approach is fine - no need to do anything fancy with the dates.

Worth noting that MongoDB filters are `AND`ed by default so you can simply your query to:

```
db.jobs.find({"state": "PENDING", "createdOn": {"$lt": newDate}})
```

I suspect your root cause is that you are querying on `state` but updating `status`.

This code sample should work:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']

# Set up some sample data

for days in range(8):
    db.jobs.insert_one({'state': 'PENDING', 'createdOn': datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=days)})

newDate = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(days=7)

db.jobs.update_many({"state": "PENDING", "createdOn": {"$lt": newDate}}, {'$set': {'state': 'FAILED'}})

pendingJobs = list(db.jobs.find({'state': 'FAILED'}))
print(pendingJobs)
```

prints:

```
[{'_id': ObjectId('5fce82c2916f9131fec02966'), 'state': 'FAILED', 'createdOn': datetime.datetime(2020, 11, 30, 19, 30, 10, 393000)}]
```